# Adding special characters to an array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a function that adds capitals, lowercase, and 0-9 to a character array and now i want to add special characters such as `!@#$%^&*()`. The format for my array goes like this:

```
 for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ++ch)
          tmp.append(ch);
        for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch)
          tmp.append(ch);
        for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch)
          tmp.append(ch);


        symbols = tmp.toString().toCharArray();
```

How do I add the special characters, using the same format if possible, without adding them one by one?

Comment: You realize that's 2^16 characters? Start at [`Character.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_VALUE) stop at [`Character.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE).

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tmp is StringBuilder or StringBuffer you can append all characters in one method call:

```
tmp.append( "!@#$%^&*()" );
```

Comment: Feel so dumb that i didn't think of this @przemek!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment Elliott made. you can add the characters !"#$%&'()*+,-./ by using

```
for(int i = 33 ; i < 48; i++)
    tmp.append(Character.toChars(i))
```

The ASCII values of the characters which I listed is from 33 to 48, they will be converted to the keyboard characters and can be appended.